# Imageview android rotation and center crop doesnot work together in API 16

Tags: android

[image]We were trying to rotate imageview with scaletype centercrop. We are setting centercrop to add parallax effect to the image on scrolling.  It works prefectly in latest android sdk versions. But we have problem in API 16 devices. When we rotate imagview it fills to show whole image. 
How can we solve this problem?

We tried replacing the custom image view with android image view. The same problem happens.

Here is our xml code.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:rotation="-10"
    android:transformPivotX="600dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.fmsirvent.ParallaxEverywhere.PEWImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_item_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_workouts"
            pew:reverse="reverseY"
            pew:parallax_x="220dp"
            pew:parallax_y="220dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:translationX="@dimen/translation_x_for_menu_text"
        android:text="WORKOUTS"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? I have same issue too!

Comment: Did you solved the problem?